# If $n \in Z^+$, how many possible values are there for $gcd(n,n+3000)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm working my way through Grimaldi's textbook, and there's one exercise in the supplementary exercises for Chapter 4 that I don't understand how to approach.

Here is the problem:  if $n \in Z^+$, how many possible values are there for $gcd(n,n+3000)$?

In case the notation $gcd(x,y)$ is not universal, it refers to the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$. I reviewed the teacher's solutions for an explanation for how to solve this problem, but it relies on the fact that $gcd(n,n+3000)$ is a divisor of $3000$, which I don't understand.  Any help on either solving the problem or explaining why $gcd(n,n+3000)$ is a common divisor of $3000$ this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: If g divides x, and g divides y, then g also divides x-y.

Comment: Let $d=\gcd(n,n+3000)\implies d|n, d|(n+3000)\implies d|3000$ (why?)
It can be shown that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$.

Comment: @Anand Thank you!  That now seems so obvious after you pointed that out.

Answer (score 4):

There are exactly $\sigma_0(3000)=32$ values.

If $d$ is divisor of 3000, Then $d=\text{gcd}(d, d+3000)$. And by Euclidean algorithm, $\text{gcd}(d, d+3000)=\text{gcd}(d, 3000)$ is divisor of 3000.

Comment: Note $\phi()$, or $\varphi()$, usually represents the [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) (with $\varphi(3000) = 2^2 \times 2 \times (4 \times 5^2) = 800$). Instead, $\sigma_{0}()$ is used to represent the number of divisors form of the [Divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), with $\sigma_{0}(3000) = 32$, as you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the greatest common divisor of x and y be (x,y), then
$$(n,n+3000)=(n,3000)$$
Since $$
3000=2^{3} \times 3 \times 5^{3}
$$ Therefore there are ***at most*** $$(3+1)\times (1+1)\times (3+1)=32$$possible values for $gcd(n,n+3000)$.

Comment: Why 0+1? 3=3¹, so it must be 1+1.

Comment: Thank you very much for catching it.